# Curve_fit is giving errors on parameters that are larger than the parameters themselves (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I've got data for a peak from an oscilloscope and have used curve_fit to fit to the data. When I use perr to try and find the errors on the fit parameters they are larger than the parameter itself.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a sample minimal code that we can reproduce?

Comment: Why is it a problem when the error bar is larger than the magnitude? Are you trying to prove something about the sign of the parameters or their non-zero contribution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur due to [Multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), i.e, some of the columns are correlated with each other. Wikipedia article states:

> multicollinearity does not actually bias results; it just produces
> large standard errors in the related independent variables

Referring to [remedies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Remedies), a common solution is to use Principal Component Regression.